# What is the Rubygem that makes it easy to release a new feature to a subset of users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, redis

I came across a Gem that had a nice way of releasing certain features to a subset of your users. I believe it even had cucumber integration, so you could write tests for different sets of users. If someone knows the name, I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rollout](http://github.com/jamesgolick/rollout)?

Answer (score 0):

There are some A/B testing frameworks that do this (albeit as a side-effect):

- [A/Bingo](http://www.bingocardcreator.com/abingo)
- [Vanity](http://vanity.labnotes.org/)